# JS Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to build a tic-tac-toe game and the result that is displayed ("winner", "tie")
works fine unless there is only one box left on the board and the player wins with that last move.
Then depending on the combination the result can be correct ("Player1 WINS") or wrong ("TIE").

Here is the code that displays the winner. Is there something wrong with it?

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let winner = document.querySelector('.winner');

const playerFactory = (name, symbol) => {
    return {name, symbol};
};

const player1 = playerFactory('Player1', 'X');
const player2 = playerFactory('Player2', 'O');

const gameBoard = (() => {
    const board = [];
    const addMark = () => {
        boxes.forEach(function(box) {
            box.addEventListener('click', () =>{ 
            if(box.textContent === '') {// Check if the box is empty
                  if (gameBoard.board[0] == null || (gameBoard.board.length > 1 &&  gameBoard.board[gameBoard.board.length - 1] == player2.symbol)){
                   gameBoard.board.push(player1.symbol); 
                }  else gameBoard.board.push(player2.symbol)    
                   box.textContent = gameBoard.board[gameBoard.board.length - 1];   
            }               
           })
        })
    }
    return {board, addMark};

})();

    gameBoard.addMark();
function displayWinner(){
            const arr =[];

            const winCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], 
                                     [0, 3, 6], 
                                     [1, 4, 7],
                                     [2, 5, 8],
                                     [3, 4, 5],
                                     [6, 7, 8],
                                     [2, 4, 6],
                                     [0, 4, 8]];

          
            boxes.forEach(box => arr.push(box.textContent));
                
                let p1Array = arr.map((item, index) => {
                    return item === "X" ? index : null;
                  }).filter(index => index !== null);

                let p2Array =  arr.map((item, index) => {
                    return item === "O" ? index : null;
                  }).filter(index => index !== null); 
                                  
                    winCombinations.forEach((elem, index) => {
                        if(winCombinations[index].every(item => p1Array.includes(item))){
                          return  winner.textContent = `${player1.name}  WINS`;
                        } else if(winCombinations[index].every(item => p2Array.includes(item))){
                          return  winner.textContent = `${player2.name}  WINS`;
                        } else if(arr.every(item => item !== '')) return winner.textContent = 'TIE';
                    });

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the code (but not more than needed) with which the wrong behaviour can be reproduced. So concretely, provide the content of `boxes` for which you have the wrong output.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with it if it doesn't show the correct results all the time. It seems win detection does more than necessary--as soon as a win is detected you can stop checking. (I'd also argue that storing winning combinations isn't needed since they're calculable, but that's a separate issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `forEach` loop has `return` statements, but those do not terminate the loop. The `forEach` callbacks will **all** be called, and if a subsequent one assigns something to `winner.textContent` then that will override any previous value assigned to it.

We can reproduce that with this snippet:

```js
// The initialisation that is needed to run the displayWinner code
const player1 = {name: "X"};
const player2 = {name: "O"};
const s = "XXX"+
          "XOO" +
          "OOX";
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("div span");
boxes.forEach((box, i) => box.textContent = s[i].trim());

// Call it
displayWinner();

function displayWinner(){
    const arr =[];

    const winCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], 
                             [0, 3, 6], 
                             [1, 4, 7],
                             [2, 5, 8],
                             [3, 4, 5],
                             [6, 7, 8],
                             [2, 4, 6],
                             [0, 4, 8]];

  
    boxes.forEach(box => arr.push(box.textContent));
    
    let p1Array = arr.map((item, index) => {
        return item === "X" ? index : null;
    }).filter(index => index !== null);

    let p2Array =  arr.map((item, index) => {
        return item === "O" ? index : null;
    }).filter(index => index !== null); 
                          
    winCombinations.forEach((elem, index) => {
        if(winCombinations[index].every(item => p1Array.includes(item))){
          return  winner.textContent = `${player1.name}  WINS`;
        } else if(winCombinations[index].every(item => p2Array.includes(item))){
          return  winner.textContent = `${player2.name}  WINS`;
        } else if(arr.every(item => item !== '')) return winner.textContent = 'TIE';
    });
}
```

```html
outcome: <span id="winner"></span><p> 

Game board:
<div>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
</div>
```

Use a `for` loop instead, so that the `return` statement ends the loop. Secondly, there is no need to check in every iteration if it is a draw. This can happen *after* the loop.

Correction:

```js
// The initialisation that is needed to run the displayWinner code
const player1 = {name: "X"};
const player2 = {name: "O"};
const s = "XXX"+
          "XOO" +
          "OOX";
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("div span");
boxes.forEach((box, i) => box.textContent = s[i].trim());

// Call it
displayWinner();

function displayWinner(){
    const arr =[];

    const winCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], 
                             [0, 3, 6], 
                             [1, 4, 7],
                             [2, 5, 8],
                             [3, 4, 5],
                             [6, 7, 8],
                             [2, 4, 6],
                             [0, 4, 8]];

  
    boxes.forEach(box => arr.push(box.textContent));
    
    let p1Array = arr.map((item, index) => {
        return item === "X" ? index : null;
    }).filter(index => index !== null);

    let p2Array =  arr.map((item, index) => {
        return item === "O" ? index : null;
    }).filter(index => index !== null); 
                          
    for (let combi of winCombinations) {
        if(combi.every(item => p1Array.includes(item))){
          return  winner.textContent = `${player1.name}  WINS`;
        } else if(combi.every(item => p2Array.includes(item))){
          return  winner.textContent = `${player2.name}  WINS`;
        }
    }
    if(arr.every(item => item !== '')) winner.textContent = 'TIE';
}
```

```html
outcome: <span id="winner"></span><p> 

Game board:
<div>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
</div>
```

Some other improvements:

- The `forEach`+`push` should better be written with `Array.from`
- There is no need for the `p1Array` or `p2Array`. Instead use the indices of winning combinations to read directly from `arr` and see if that is "XXX" or "OOO".
- For the tie check you can use `Boolean` as callback for `every`.

So:

```js
// The initialisation that is needed to run the displayWinner code
const player1 = {name: "X"};
const player2 = {name: "O"};
const s = "XXX"+
          "XOO" +
          "OOX";
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("div span");
boxes.forEach((box, i) => box.textContent = s[i].trim());

// Call it
displayWinner();

function displayWinner(){
    const winCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], 
                             [0, 3, 6], 
                             [1, 4, 7],
                             [2, 5, 8],
                             [3, 4, 5],
                             [6, 7, 8],
                             [2, 4, 6],
                             [0, 4, 8]];

    const arr = Array.from(boxes, box => box.textContent);

    for (const combi of winCombinations) {
        const three = combi.map(item => arr[item]).join("");
        if (three == "XXX") {
          return winner.textContent = `${player1.name}  WINS`;
        } else if (three == "OOO") {
          return winner.textContent = `${player2.name}  WINS`;
        }
    }
    if (arr.every(Boolean)) winner.textContent = 'TIE';
}
```

```html
outcome: <span id="winner"></span><p> 

Game board:
<div>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please further explain the initialization code?
Is it necessary?
Or can i just add an EventListener that calls the function every time a mark is placed?

Comment: I added initialisation code only because I wanted something that could be run in my answer. So no, you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on getting a Tic-Tac-Toe engine working, before I worry about rendering the HTML portion. Keeping the game state in a single object would help you out greatly.

Checking for win conditions can be done with nested for-loops. Each condition could be broken into smaller functions.

```js
const main = () => {
  const gameState = {
    players: [
      { name: 'O' },
      { name: 'X' }
    ],
    grid: [
      [{ occupant: 0 }, { occupant: 1 }, { occupant: 1 }],
      [{ occupant: 0 }, { occupant: 1 }, { occupant: 0 }],
      [{ occupant: 1 }, { occupant: 0 }, { occupant: 0 }],
    ],
    turn: 9
  };
  // Test the engine
  console.log(isWinner('X', gameState)); // true
  console.log(isWinner('O', gameState)); // false
  console.log(isTie(gameState));         // false
  console.log(isDone(gameState));        // true

  // Render the HTML
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.board span');
  boxes.forEach((box, index) => {
    const
      row = Math.floor(index / gameState.grid.length),
      col = index % gameState.grid.length;
    box.innerText = gameState.players[gameState.grid[row][col].occupant]?.name ?? '';
  });
  const winner = document.querySelector('#winner');
  if (isWinner(gameState.players[0].name, gameState)) {
    winner.innerText = `Player ${gameState.players[0].name} wins`;
  } else if (isWinner(gameState.players[1].name, gameState)) {
    winner.innerText = `Player ${gameState.players[1].name} wins`;
  } else if (isTie(gameState)) {
    winner.innerText = `Tie!`;
  }
};

const isWinnerLine = (player, state, line, transpose) => {
  for (let col = 0; col < state.grid[line].length; col++) {
    const cell = transpose ? state.grid[col][line] : state.grid[line][col];
    if (state.players[cell.occupant]?.name !== player) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

const isWinnerLines = (player, state, transpose) => {
  for (let line = 0; line < state.grid.length; line++) {
    if (!isWinnerLine(player, state, line, transpose)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};

const isWinnerDiagonal = (player, state, transpose) => {
  for (let r = 0; r < state.grid.length; r++) {
    const cell = transpose ? state.grid[state.grid.length - r - 1][r] : state.grid[r][r];
    if (state.players[cell.occupant]?.name !== player) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const isWinnerRows = (player, state, transpose) =>
  isWinnerLines(player, state);

const isWinnerColumns = (player, state) =>
  isWinnerLines(player, state, true);

const isWinnerDiagonals = (player, state) =>
  isWinnerDiagonal(player, state) ||
  isWinnerDiagonal(player, state, true)

const isWinner = (player, state) =>
  isWinnerRows(player, state) ||
  isWinnerColumns(player, state) ||
  isWinnerDiagonals(player, state);

const isDone = (state) =>
  state.grid.every(row => row.every(cell => cell.occupant > -1));

const isTie = (state) => // could check state.turn > 8 instead.
  isDone(state) &&
  !isWinner(state.players[0].name, state) &&
  !isWinner(state.players[1].name, state);

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
Outcome: <span id="winner"></span><p> 

Game board:
<div class="board">
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
<span></span><span></span><span></span><br>
</div>
```